# How to efficiently implement training multiple related time series in Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I have 5 time series that I want a neural network to predict. The time series are related to each other. Each time series consists of numbers between 0 and 100. I want to predict the next number for each time series. I already have a model to train one time series using a GRU and that works reasonably well. I have tried two strategies:

1. I normalized the numbers and made the problem a regression problem. The best validation accuracy so far is 0.38.
2. I one-hot-encoded the time series, and this works significantly better (an added accuracy of 0.15) but it costs 100 times as much memory.

For 5 time series, I tried 5 independent models but in that case the relationship between the 5 time series was lost. I am wondering what an efficient strategy to proceed might be. I can think of two myself but I might be missing something:

1. I can stack the input so that I have a five-hot-encoded input instead of 5 one-hot-encoded. Can this be done?
2. I can create 5 models and merge them. I am not sure what to do with the output. Should I split the model, one for each time series?

Is there a strategy I have overlooked? Memory is a problem. With thousands of time series, with sample lengths of 100, the data uses a lot of memory and processing time. I Googled around but could not find an efficient strategy. Could someone suggest how to implement this problem efficiently in Keras?

Comment: Are the five timeseries/sequences of same nature? For example, suppose you want to create a model that predicts the similarity of two sentences; So in this case, we have two timeseries as inputs of the model, but they are both sequences of words (i.e. same nature).

Comment: Yes, they are all music notes.

Comment: Then have you tried Siamese/Shared LSTM approach?

Comment: That is an interesting suggestion, I'll try that first thing tomorrow. Thank!